# Solspace: Dates are not saving

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Calendar: 1.8.5 & EE 2.7.3

Calendar dates are not saving in channel ( calendar : events )

**I tried this so far:**

1. uninstalled and re-installed the module but it did not help
2. I tried downgrading to calendar: 1.6.4 also did not work, I think because calender 1.8.5 might have changed the DB in some way. Going back was giving me some errors, and saving was still not working.

When you hit "save" no calendar data is saved in the control panel. Unable to change dates on existing entries that used to work under solspace calendar: 1.6.4

---

setup used to work good under: EE 2.5.3 & Calendar 1.6.4

any one else have this happen?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I have to manually add a row to the exp_calendar_events table.

Comment: I solved the issue by resetting the "views" in the control panel